# Resize EditText to fit Text Size

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am looking to resize an EditText height, based on the height of the text size.

The reason I want to do this is because some users will set their text size to "Large" inside the Android Accessibility Options, and than some of the text will be cut off within my applications EditText views.

**What can I do to dynamically adjust the height to match the Text Size?** I do not need auto resizing or anything fancy.

Here is some code inside my custom EditText Class

```
    mCurrentTextSize = getTextSize();
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                                                DisplayUtils.pixel2dp(getContext(), mCurrentTextSize));
    setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Inside a Utility Class

```
public static int pixel2dp(Context context, float pixel) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
    float logicalDensity = metrics.density;

    return (int) Math.ceil(pixel / logicalDensity);
}
```

Comment: So you actually the height to be flexible but also displaying one line only?

Comment: I would like to only use 1 line. In my application the Edit Text is wide enough, but it in not tall enough once the user changes the Text Size in the phone.

Comment: Just wondering: setting layout height param to `WRAP_CONTENT` and then using `setSingleLine(true)` over you control, it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `layout_height=wrap_content`? It will automatically re-adjust the EditText so as to contain the text.